# wtangled arrays in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have two tables: $official_table and $unofficial_table:

all I do with this tables is here:

```
<?php
$official_table=array();
$unofficial_table=array();
(...)
for($i=0;$i<pg_Num_Rows($result3);$i++) {
  $row=pg_Fetch_Object($result3,$i);
  if ($row->official=='t') {
    $official_table[$row->branch_id][$row->first_name.' '.$row->last_name][$row->day]=$row;
} else {
   $unofficial_table[$row->branch_id][$row->first_name.' '.$row->last_name][$row->day]=$row;
} 
(...)
for($i=0;$i<pg_Num_Rows($result3);$i++) {
  $row=pg_Fetch_Object($result3,$i);

    $official_table[0][$row->first_name.' '.$row->last_name][$row->day]=$row;
    $official_table[0][$row->first_name.' '.$row->last_name][$row->day]->range="Y".substr($row->time_begin,0,5)."-".substr($row->time_end,0,5);
    echo $official_table[0][$row->first_name.' '.$row->last_name][$row->day]->range."<br>";
    $unofficial_table[0][$row->first_name.' '.$row->last_name][$row->day]=$row;
    $unofficial_table[0][$row->first_name.' '.$row->last_name][$row->day]->range="X".substr($row->time_begin,0,5)."-".substr($row->time_end,0,5);
    echo $unofficial_table[0][$row->first_name.' '.$row->last_name][$row->day]->range."<br>";
    echo $official_table[0][$row->first_name.' '.$row->last_name][$row->day]->range."<br>";
}
?>
```

And the result is more then unexpected: at the end both tables has 'X', while official should have 'Y'!!!

```
Y15:00-23:59
X15:00-23:59
X15:00-23:59
```

what is happening? I checked twice if somewhere is some attribution like $official_table=$unofficial_table, but nothing found.... How to debug this? Is there a reference to table or pointer, which I can check line after line?

Comment: You need `=clone $row` everywhere you assign `$row`.Without that objects in PHP modify all variables that 'point to it'. But there are not (PHP) references, and certainly not (C) pointers. If you just google the clone keyword, the manual should explain why. Or somebody else gives a full answer.

Comment: :O I'm shocked.. When I think about it now - it is obvious. But now I see, that I have to check all my scripts ;D

Comment: @jh1711 please make an answer of this...